# Issue with ManyToOne adding foreign constraint to FOS_User_Bundle user table

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity, many-to-one

I'm running into an issue with adding a foreign key constraint to my fos_user table. Specifically the issue is with a ManyToOne relationship. I haven't run into this issue doing ManyToOne and OneToMany relationships on another other entities, just this one.

Error Message:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                             
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE fos_user ADD CONS  
  TRAINT FK_957A6479309D1878 FOREIGN KEY (university_id) REFERENCES Un  
  iversities (id)':                                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constrai  
  nt
```

Entity:

```
namespace Project\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project\UserBundle\Entity\Universities", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $university;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that there is an issue with creating a foreign key on the fos_user table, and that by exporting the databases, dropping the db and then re-creating it the mapping works.